# Time and temperature displaying program for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, beginner, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

This program displays either the time, current temperature, 12hr graph of temps, 24 hr graph of temp or a week's graph of temps.  Selection is based on user input of one of the GPIO pins.

Please review my code, especially the use of the global variables, indentation and comments.

```
from subprocess import *
import matplotlib
from  numpy import genfromtxt
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import pylab
import Image
import pygame
import os
import time
from time import strftime
#from pygame.locals import*
#from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime

def run_cmd(cmd):
      """Used to run Linux commands"""
      p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
      output = p.communicate()[0]
      return output

def ckyorn( prompt, help="" ):
    """Used for Y/N prompt"""
    a= ""
    ok= False
    while not ok:
        a=raw_input( prompt + " [y,n,?]: " )
        if a.upper() in [ 'Y', 'N', 'YES', 'NO' ]:
            ok= True
    return a.upper()[0]

def delete_old_data():
    """ Used to delete old data in input file. Will check for data older than 14 days
    and ask if you would like everything older than 7 days to be deleted. This should     not being asked more than once a week"""
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    #get the first line of the data file, which will be the oldest entry
    getfirstLine = run_cmd("head -1 temperature_logging | awk '{print $2}'")
    #convert string to time.
    firstLineTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(getfirstLine, '%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S ')

    #Get the date and time for seven days ago from now.
    sevenDays = now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    removeFrom =  sevenDays.strftime('%m-%d-%Y-%T')

    #If the data and time in the first line is older than 14 days, ask if okay to     delete.
    if (now - firstLineTime) > datetime.timedelta(days=14):
        print ("More than 14 days worth of data has been collected.")
        var = ckyorn ("Would you like to delete data older than 7 days?")
        if var == 'Y' :
            sedCommand = "sed -n -i  '/" + removeFrom[1:15] + "/,$p' temperature_logging"
            run_cmd(sedCommand)

def displayText(text, size, line, color, clearScreen):

    """Used to display text to the screen. displayText is only configured to display 
    two lines on the TFT. Only clear screen when writing the first line"""
    if clearScreen == True:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size)
    text = font.render(text, 0, color)
    textRotated = pygame.transform.rotate(text, -90)
    textpos = textRotated.get_rect()
    textpos.centery = 80    
    if line == 1:
         textpos.centerx = 90
         screen.blit(textRotated,textpos)
    elif line == 2:
        textpos.centerx = 40
        screen.blit(textRotated,textpos)


def displayTime():
    """Used to display date and time on the TFT"""
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    currentTimeLine1 = strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    currentTimeLine2 = strftime("%d  %b", time.localtime())

    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
    text1 = font.render(currentTimeLine1, 0, (0,250,150))
    text2 = font.render(currentTimeLine2, 0, (0,250,150))

    Surf1 = pygame.transform.rotate(text1, -90)
    Surf2 = pygame.transform.rotate(text2, -90)

    screen.blit(Surf1,(60,20))
    screen.blit(Surf2,(10,20))

def graph(toKeep):
    """Used to display the graphs. Text will be shown before hand as
    the graphs take time to generate"""
    global firstTime

    #Display some text stating that graphs are being generated 
    if toKeep == TwelveHours:
        displayText('Creating', 35, 1,(200,200,1),True)
        displayText('12 Hour Graph', 32, 2,(150,150,255), False)
    elif toKeep == TwentyFourHours:
        displayText('Creating', 35, 1,(200,200,1), True)
        displayText('24 Hour Graph', 32, 2,(150,150,255), False)
    elif toKeep == OneWeek:
        displayText('Creating', 35, 1,(200,200,1), True)
        displayText('One Week Graph', 28, 2,(150,150,255), False)
    pygame.display.flip()

    #Get temperature and time data from data file
    temp = genfromtxt('temperature_logging', dtype=None, usecols=(0), skip_header = lines - toKeep)
    timecaptured = genfromtxt('temperature_logging', dtype=None, usecols=(1), skip_header = lines - toKeep)

    #Site the size of the font for the axis
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(8)
    for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(8)

    #Create xaxis labels and only show every 12th or 96th
    xlabels = range(toKeep)
    if toKeep == OneWeek:
        pylab.xticks(xlabels[::96], [v[:5:] for v in timecaptured[::96]])
    else:
        pylab.xticks(xlabels[::12], [v[11:16] for v in timecaptured[::12]])

    #Plot the graph
    pylab.plot(temp,linewidth=2, antialiased=True)

    #Change some colours
    ax.patch.set_facecolor('#FFFFCC')
    ax.patch.set_alpha(0.5)

    #Rotate the text in the xaxis
    fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
    #Set the yaxsis limits
    pylab.ylim(0,40)

    #Save the graph as an image and the re-open it, rotate it and then display to TFT.
    pylab.savefig('gp.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(),bbox_inches='tight', dpi=80,pad_inches=0.03)
    pil_im = Image.open('gp.png')
    pil_out = pil_im.rotate(-90)
    pil_out.save("gp.png")
    img = pygame.image.load('gp.png')
    screen.blit(img,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    #Clear graph data in preparation for next plot
    pylab.cla()

    #Reset the firstTime Variable
    firstTime = 0

def main():
  global ax,fig,screen
  global firstTime,lines
  global TwentyFourHours,TwelveHours,OneWeek

  size = width, height = 128, 160
  TFTxSize = 2.28
  TFTySize = 1.63
  firstTime = True      #Used to work out if a function has already been run
  TwentyFourHours = 288
  TwelveHours = 144
  OneWeek = 2016

  whatToDisplay = 1     #What do display on screen
  rotate = 2            #Used when automatically rotating the display.
  startTime = time.time()   #Used to work out how much time has passed when rotating.

  #Set the framebuffer device to be the TFT
  os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"

  #Setup pygame display
  pygame.init()
  pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)



  #Setup plot area
  fig = pylab.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  fig.set_size_inches(TFTxSize, TFTySize)
  background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
  background = background.convert()


  #Setup GPIO
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
  GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN) #Read GPIO 17 as input


  #Open data file and count how many lines
  file = open('temperature_logging')
  lines = sum(1 for word in file if "." in word)
  file.seek(0,0)


  delete_old_data()

  while True:
      time.sleep(.5)
      """Check to see if button is pressed, and if so, increment by  one
      or reset to one if over 6"""
      if GPIO.input(17):
          if whatToDisplay < 7:
              whatToDisplay = whatToDisplay + 1
              firstTime = True
          else:
              whatToDisplay = 1
              firstTime = True
      import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
      if whatToDisplay == 1:    #Display time
          displayTime()
      elif whatToDisplay == 2:  #Display last temperature recorded.
          file.seek(-26,2)      #Go to end of data file to get temperature
          currentTemp = file.readline(5) + ' \xb0C'
          displayText('Current Temp', 30, 1, (200,200,1), True )
          displayText(currentTemp, 50, 2, (150,150,255), False )
      elif  whatToDisplay == 4 and firstTime == True:
          graph(TwelveHours)
      elif  whatToDisplay  == 5 and firstTime == True:
          graph(TwentyFourHours)
      elif  whatToDisplay == 6 and firstTime == True:
          graph(OneWeek)
      elif  whatToDisplay == 3: #Rotate display
          elapsedTime = time.time() - startTime
          if elapsedTime > 5:
              if rotate == 1:
                  rotate = 2
                  startTime = time.time()
              else:
                  rotate = 1
                  startTime = time.time()
              if rotate == 1:
                  displayTime()
          elif rotate == 2:
              file.seek(-26,2)
              currentTemp = file.readline(5) + ' \xb0C'
                  displayText('Current Temp', 30, 1, (200,200,1), True )
              displayText(currentTemp, 50, 2, (150,150,255), False )
      #Write to TFT
      pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I see that you have accepted my answer. Don't you want to put a new version of your code here so that one can have a deeper look ?

Comment: I'd love to see the new and improved version too :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Too much to put as a comment, so this is going to be an answer :

As a general comment, you use many variables which are used only once, so they might not really be useful.

`ckyorn` can be rewritten in a more concise way. Also, its name is weird and one of the parameters is not used.

```
def ckyorn( prompt):
    """Used for Y/N prompt"""
    while True:
        a=raw_input( prompt + " [y,n,?]: " ).upper()
        if a in [ 'Y', 'N', 'YES', 'NO' ]: 
            return a[0]
```

I think it would make sense if this function was to return a boolean instead of a string.

```
        if a in [ 'Y', 'YES']: 
            return True
        if a in [ 'N', 'No']: 
            return False
```

And then, the calling code becomes clearer :

```
if ckyorn ("Would you like to delete data older than 7 days?"):
```

You can write `if clearScreen:` instead of `if clearScreen == True:`. This applies to different parts of your code.

Make sure you always extract common code from then and else blocks. For instance,

```
      if whatToDisplay < 7:
          whatToDisplay = whatToDisplay + 1
          firstTime = True
      else:
          whatToDisplay = 1
          firstTime = True
```

is exactly the same as :

```
      if whatToDisplay < 7:
          whatToDisplay = whatToDisplay + 1
      else:
          whatToDisplay = 1
      firstTime = True
```

Please note that what you are doing on `whatToDisplay` could be done with the modular operator:

```
      whatToDisplay = 1+(whatToDisplay%7)
```

Data structures can be used to extract common code. For instance `displayTime` could be :

```
def displayTime():
     """Used to display date and time on the TFT"""
     screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
     font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
     now=time.localtime()
     for setting in [("%H:%M:%S",60),("%d  %b",10)] :
         timeformat,dim=setting
         currentTimeLine = strftime(timeformat, now)
         text = font.render(currentTimeLine, 0, (0,250,150))
         Surf = pygame.transform.rotate(text, -90)
         screen.blit(Surf,(dim,20))
```

I haven't looked at it much so far but the global variables seem dodgy to me.

My intuition is that rotation should actually be a boolean as it takes only 2 different values. Then,

```
      if elapsedTime > 5:
          if rotate == 1:
              rotate = 2
              startTime = time.time()
          else:
              rotate = 1
              startTime = time.time()
          if rotate == 1:
              displayTime()
      elif rotate == 2:
          file.seek(-26,2)
```

would become :

```
      if elapsedTime > 5:
          rotate = not rotate
          startTime = time.time()
          if rotate:
              displayTime()
      elif not rotate:
          file.seek(-26,2)
```

**Edit**
After a second look at `delete_old_data` :

- The variables names are not really good. In particular :

  - `getfirstline` should be `firstline`
  - `sevenDays` should be something like `sevenDaysAgo`
  - `removeFrom` should be something like `sevenDaysAgoStr`
- You probably don't need to call shell command as you could do the same things in pure Python.
- The name of the file (`temperature_logging`) should appear only once in the code (you store it in a variable). The same applies to `gp.png` later in the code.
- `sevenDays` and `removeFrom` should be defined in the smallest possible scope. In your case, you don't need them until after `if var == 'Y'`.
- I don't know why you want to take the letters 1 from 15 in `removeFrom`. Can't you just make sure that `removeFrom` is formatted just the way you want using `strftime`?

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time with looking at my code. Its muchly appreciated.
All your points are very much valid… and I have learned a great deal.

I had no idea you can use the modulo operator to rotate a number like that……  a lot cleaner than what I was doing!

And what you did to Def displayTime(): … again, I had no idea you could do this and it looks much more efficient. 

I’m going to go away and work on your other points.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Josay Your modular-operator-solution for `whatToDisplay` only does the same thing as the original code for values between 0 and (including) 7. For values > 7, it's totally different.

Comment: Actually, the point is that it never takes a value > 7. By making sure that this variable is only changed by this single statement, I think it enforces this and makes it clearer (only one branch to consider instead of 2 in the if-else structure). However, I do agree that more generally speaking, the two pieces of code have different effects.

Comment: Also, this could be even clearer if we were to use values in [0,6] instead of values in [1,7] by re-indexing every thing. Then, we would just have : "whatToDisplay = whatToDisplay%7"